# Animate from current position in CAAnimation

Tags: ios, cocoa, caanimation

[image: Animation representation]

How do I animate **position** of red ball from `A` to `B` starting from **C** ?
i.e. It should first animate from `C` to `B` and then animate indefinately between `A` & `B`

---

I have following code snippet

```
animation.fromValue = A
animation.toValue = B
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
animation.duration = 2.0
```

The problem with this code snippet is that resets the position to `A` before starting the animation.
I want the animation to start from `C` to `B` and then animate between `A` and `C`

Comment: Is the object actually at position C, or is it a previous animation that was stopped at position C?

Comment: Layers position is set to C, when it is added as a sublayer to its parent layer

Answer (score 1):

you will probably need to use 2 different animations: One from position C to position B, and then a repeating, auto-reversing animation from B back to A. If you can use it, UIView animations are much easier to use than CAAnimations. I'd try UIView animations first before diving into CAAnimation objects.

Comment: I cannot use `UIView` because I need it in multiplatform (iOS and OS X)project. I also think if there is no option, other than using 2 animations

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.circleView.frame
            frame.origin = A
            self.circleView.frame = frame
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPoint(x: A, y: self.circleView.frame.origin.y))
            animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPoint(x: B, y: self.circleView.frame.origin.y))
            animation.removedOnCompletion = false
            animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            animation.duration = 2.0
            self.circleView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")

    }
```

If you want to have it reversible instead of jumping to A point whenever it reaches to B, you can also add `animation.autoreverses = true`